# How to hide label if it doesn't fit in your line of sight in Apache ECharts

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-superset

I am using Apache Superset and for the bar chart I am using Apache ECharts. I am displaying the data with stacked style = stack to combine. I only need to display the data if it fits in its own line, otherwise hide. How can this be realized ?

Right now it looks like this

[image]

I tried setting in series - **labelLayout: {hideOverlap: true}**

It's not much better, but the problem remains.

[image]

This hides labels that overlap each other, but I need labels that don't fit in their lines to be hidden.